# Tensorflow - Next batch of data from tf.train.shuffle_batch

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a `tfrecords` file from which I am looking to create batches of data. I am using `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` to create a single batch. In my training I want to call the batches and pass them. And this is where I am stuck. I read that the  the poistion of the `TFRecordReader()` gets saved in the state of the graph and the next example is read from the subsequent position. The trouble is I'm not able to figure how do I load the next batch. I'm using the below code to create the batches.

```
def read_and_decode_single_example(filename):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename], num_epochs=1)
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
            'context': tf.FixedLenFeature([160], tf.int64),
            'context_len': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
            'utterance': tf.FixedLenFeature([160], tf.int64),
            'utterance_len': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64)
        })

    contexts = features['context']
    context_lens = features['context_len']
    utterances = features['utterance']
    utterance_lens = features['utterance_len']
    labels = features['label']

    return contexts, context_lens, utterances, utterance_lens, labels

contexts, context_lens, utterances, utterance_lens, labels = \
    read_and_decode_single_example('data/train.tfrecords')

contexts_batch, context_lens_batch, \
    utterances_batch, utterance_lens_batch, \
    labels_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([contexts, context_lens, utterances,
                                          utterance_lens, labels],
                                          batch_size=batch_size,
                                          capacity=3*batch_size,
                                          min_after_dequeue=batch_size)
```

This gives me a single batch of data. I want to use the `feed_dict` paradigm to pass the batches for the training wherein on each iteration, a new batch gets passed in. How do I load these batches? Will calling the `read_and_decode` along with `tf.train.shuffle_batch` again call the next batch?

Answer (score 1):

The `read_and_decode_single_example()` function creates a (sub-)graph for the network that is used to load data; you only call that once. It might be more appropriately called `build_read_and_decode_single_example_graph()`, but that's a bit long.

The "magic" lies in evaluating (i.e. using) the `_batch` tensors multiple times, e.g.

```
batch_size = 100
# ...

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # get the first batch of 100 values
    first_batch = sess.run([contexts_batch, context_lens_batch,
                            utterances_batch, utterance_lens_batch,
                            labels_batch])

    # second batch of different 100 values
    second_batch = sess.run([contexts_batch, context_lens_batch,
                            utterances_batch, utterance_lens_batch,
                            labels_batch])
    # etc.
```

Of course, rather than fetching these values from a session manually, you would feed them into some other part of the network instead. The mechanism is the same: Whenever one of these tensors is fetched directly or indirectly, the batching mechanism will take care of providing you a new batch (of different values) each time.

Comment: Couple of questions
`first_batch = sess.run([contexts_batch, context_lens_batch,
                            utterances_batch, utterance_lens_batch,
                            labels_batch])`

Comment: I think you forgot to type in the actual question. :)

Comment: I remember deleting that comment. Anyway I figured it. Thanks